# Need to create sequence of date intervals

Tags: r

I need to create shift timings for next 15 days

So I am trying like this:

```
library(lubridate)  
c = matrix(nrow=360, ncol=45)  
date1 <- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 00:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern")  
date2 <- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 08:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern")  
date3<- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 16:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern")  
date4<- ymd_hms("2000-02-01 00:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern")
```

I created three shift intervals for day1 as follows:

```
shift1<-interval(date1,date2)  
shift2<-interval(date2,date3)  
shift3<-interval(date4,date3)
```

And I want to create similar intervals for next 14 days. I am trying like this:

```
end<-as.matrix(rep(c(shift1,shift2,shift3)+days(1),14)))
```

This is the error

> Error in per@.Data + num : 
>     Arithmetic operators undefined for 'numeric' and 'Interval' classes:
>     convert one to numeric or a matching time-span class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this `apply` family solution?

```
library(lubridate)    
date1 <- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 00:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern")  



end<- lapply(0:14, function(x){
                              lapply(c(0,8,16), function(y){
                                interval((date1+days(x)+hours(y)), (date1+days(x)+hours(y+8)))
                              })
                              })
```

`lapply(0:14)` will create group of intervals from day 0 to day 14 starting in `date1`
`lapply(c(0,8,16)` will create n+1 intervals where n = `c(0,8,16)` starting from date1 + day X (X determined by first `lapply`)

The result will be a `list of lists` where for example `end[[8]][3]` will be the 3rd intervals of day 8 starting `date1`

Best!

Comment: Thanks  How to convert this list to single row I am trying like this unlist(end)

Comment: I am not in front of my pc now but how about rbindlist, my friend?

Comment: No my friend, I have hourly data  created below I am trying to check whether particular hour falls in each interval 
time_index <-seq(from = as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern"), 
                 to = as.POSIXct("2000-01-15 23:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern"), by = "hour")

Comment: Hi solved by writing loop like this     for (i in 1:15){
  for (j in 1:3){
    tmp<- ifelse(row%within%shifts[[i]][j], 1,0)
    df<-cbind(df, tmp)
  }
}      But How to handle if i want to increment shift timings by 2.5 hours